# Ignore a Smarty Templates Fetch() for one page

Tags: php, css, templates, smarty

I've just been passed an application to work on written in smarty templates so I'm unfamiliar with how the whole thing works.

So my problem is smarty is fetching a template from a file at application level so it affects every page on the site. I need a way of telling a single template to ignore the application level fetch.

So at application level it is echo $smarty->fetch('layout/main.html.tpl'); I just want to ignore that on one template. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to add some logic to whatever point in the application is fetching that template.  The issue isn't smarty, it's the application.  A smarty template has no way of interfering with the php that renders it, nor can it introduce logic within the php script.

Answer (score 0):

You would call $smarty->fetch() from a script, not a template.  You can use logic to choose a different template name and fetch whatever template is appropriate, so a single script can easily call any of your templates.

For instance...

```
$template = 'error.tpl';
if($conditions =='right')
{
    $template = 'normal.tpl';
}

echo $smarty->fetch("layout/$template");
```

Also, note that you can use the display() method rather than echo with fetch():

```
$smarty->display("layout/$template");
```

This way you're not storing the template into a variable you're just going to output.

If it's a simple case where one script calls template "A" and another calls template "B"...

```
//call in template A
$smarty->display("layout/templateA.tpl");

//call in template B
$smarty->display("layout/templateB.tpl");
```

No need for extra logic in that case.

Comment: Thanks Surreal, is there nothing I can just stick in the relevant script attached to template, sort of like controllers in rails?

Comment: I've added on to the end of my answer.  If you're looking for a more MVC solution, Smarty doesn't handle that - it's a templating system, just the view.  You'll have to provide the model and controller yourself.

Comment: Funnily enough I'm currently rewriting the site in rails, I've just been landed with this smarty system and I'm not a php dev.

Comment: I wouldn't opt for a rails system and Smarty templates, that's... odd.  I'm no rails dev, but doesn't it have its own template system built in?